# Debian and my new AMD Ryzen 2700U (Vega 10) aren't friendly

Tags: debian, xorg, drivers, amd-graphics

I was happy with my new laptop with AMD Ryzen 5 2700U and Vega 10 graphic card until I tried to install Debian Stretch.

I read a lot about the problems with new Ryzen and old kernels. I can't found official drivers on AMD website and I tried install some else linux flavours but the result was all ways the same: not hardware graphics acceleration. Also tried install backports repositories and update kernel to 4.18 instead 4.9 on stable version. 1FPS say me the graphics benchmark (Phoronix Test Suite).

I tried install amd-graphics package too, but I don't know which is better or recommendable: `firmware-amd-graphics` or `xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu` or any other that even I don't know what exists.

Any recommendation to run Debian (or another distribution if is better for AMD) and reap the benefits of the Vega 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Ryzen 3 2200G, I am running Debian/testing. First recommendation would be, either testing or unstable. Stable is too old and backports only work so much.

Next, get the latest kernel here: [linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries](https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries)
It should work decently: HDMI, audio over HDMI, suspend/resume for sure (direct experience); my system is a desktop, so your results with a laptop might vary. 
Be sure to pick the non-Ubuntu variants, however.

EDIT: I haven't been able to get resume to work correctly with kernels newer than 5.1.x, please keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

New hardware requires new software. Here's a list for popular distributions that package the latest software.

- Fedora
- Manjaro
- Opensuse Leap (Tumbleweed if you are adventurous)
- Ubuntu (Latest non-LTS)

I've got a Dell Latitude with an AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 2500U (Vega 8). I have been using it for programming since August 2018. I have tried various distributions and find Fedora 29 to be the best solution for me without making any changes to the system. I tried Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and 18.04.1 LTS but found the system to crash often, perhaps Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS will have better Vega support? I have tried playing games, but not many. Factorio runs in 1920x1080 without the breaking a sweat.

Reference (`glxinfo`):

```
OpenGL renderer string: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.27.0, 4.20.7-200.fc29.x86_64, LLVM 7.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.2.8
```

Comment: Instead of "just" implying a change of distribution, it could have been a good idea to propose to switch to Debian `testing` or `unstable` first.