# Cannot start Devuan/Debian installation

Tags: system-installation, debian-installer, thinkpad, devuan

I have a problem installing Devuan Linux 2.0 from an USB memory stick.

What happens is that after the first menu, where I have to select graphic/textual installation, all I get is a blank screen.

I tried with all combinations of the following options, which all have the same issue:

- Create USB stick with Rufus 3.5, in ISO mode.
- Create USB stick with Rufus 3.5, in DD mode.
- Install the netinst image.
- Install the whole DVD image.

I already set the BIOS options to disable secure boot and UEFI/Legacy boot to both.

These are my system details:

- Lenovo ThinkPad E585 (AMD Ryzen 7).
- Two internal SSD drives (NVMe and SATA3).

Comment: Are you running the installer in UEFI mode or legacy?

Comment: @Paradox - I set the BIOS to work in what I think should be a kind of mixed mode: "UEFI/Legacy boot to both". I did not see any option to select UEFI or legacy mode from the installer...

Comment: @Pietro I was talking about the Debian installer.

Comment: @Paradox - How can I choose whether to run the installer in UEFI or legacy mode? I thought it depended on the BIOS settings...

Comment: It depends on your motherboard: usually either inside the bios to boot on the USB drive (you can have the prefix "EFI" and then 2 choice such as "[EFI] USB_NAME" or "USE_NAME", the latter being in "legacy mode") or, if supported, by pressing F12 during the POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the AMD Ryzen 7 2700U + Vega 10 is not supported by Linux kernels before version 4.10, and both Debian and Devuan stable are on kernel 4.9.
Kernels 4.18 and newer are suggested for this AMD processor.

#### References:

https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2017/03/msg00063.html
https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries
[Debian and my new AMD Ryzen 2700U (Vega 10) aren't friendly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487571/debian-and-my-new-amd-ryzen-2700u-vega-10-arent-friendly)
https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/8snkup/most_stable_gnulinux_distro_for_a_ryzen_cpu/
https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/8hwts3/is_it_possible_to_install_debian_on_amd_ryzen/
https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/819/linux-going-amd-ryzen-cpu-debian-strech-9

---

P.S.: The newer kernel did not solve my issue. Please see here: [Cannot run/install Linux on ThinkPad E585](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/512302/cannot-run-install-linux-on-thinkpad-e585)