# Cannot run/install Linux on AMD based ThinkPad E585

Tags: linux, system-installation, laptop, thinkpad

I am not able to run/install Linux on my Lenovo ThinkPad E585. I tried both a full installation and running from the USB stick.

All I get is:

- GRUB starting from the USB stick.
- Select Linux installer from the USB stick.
- A blank screen.

This is what I tried so far:

- Distributions: Devuan, Debian, Manjaro, Artix.

  - `devuan_ascii_2.0.0_amd64_netinst.iso`
  - `debian-9.8.0-amd64-netinst.iso`
  - `manjaro-kde-18.0.4-stable-x86_64.iso`
  - `artix-lxqt-openrc-gremlins-20190222-x86_64.iso`
- Installation media: USB stick.
- Installation types: local, network.
- BIOS settings: boot from USB port first; disable secure boot and UEFI/Legacy boot to both.
- Tool to burn the OS: Rufus 3.5.1497. Tried both ISO and DD modes.
- Partition scheme: GPT/UEFI (non CSM).
- Init systems: SystemD (Debian, Manjaro), OpenRC (Devuan, Artix).

These are the laptop's specifications:

- Lenovo ThinkPad E585 (AMD Ryzen 7 2700U, 8+16 GB RAM).
- Two internal SSD drives (NVMe and SATA3).
- Working fine with Windows 10.

I found out that to support the AMD Ryzen 7 2700U processor I need at least a kernel version 4.10. Debian 9.8 has version 4.9.30, Devuan 2 has version 4.9.82, Manjaro 18 has version 4.19.28 and Artix has version 4.18.10. So the first two ones should fail to install, but the last two ones should succeed; what happens to me is that they all fail in the same way, i.e. a blank screen after GRUB selection.

The fact I chose a GPT partition scheme instead of a MBR one should not be relevant at this stage.

I ran out of ideas.

References:

- [Cannot even start Devuan/Debian installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510488/cannot-even-start-devuan-debian-installation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Linux on a Lenovo ThinkPad E585, it is necessary to upgrade the BIOS. The one provided (at least when I bought it) has some issue, which have now been fixed with the end-of-August 2019 release.

With the new BIOS, the installation is as smooth as usual.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Fedora 29 64bit on my E585. I followed the guide on [Getting Linux to boot on Lenovo Thinkpad E485/E585](https://evilazrael.de/comment/952). Especially the kernel boot parameters `ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[33]=00:00.1` seem to be important. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with these things so I can just provide the link to this guide.

Answer (score 1):

I have a E585 with the Ryzen 5 2500u and had the same issue. You need to add noapic to grub by hitting "e" when you are in the grub menu. More details and steps at [my blog](http://gordonsnotes.com/2019/03/03/fedora-on-ryzen-5-and-vega-8-install-issue/).

Answer (score 0):

Pietro, in [my experience](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/487589/325315) you need a slightly newer kernel than those: I started getting a usable system after 4.20 and I got up to 5.0.4.

You can always install in text mode and later update the kernel, of course.

Comment: Andrea, my problem is that I cannot even install a base Linux system, from which to make an upgrade. Not even an USB live distro.

Comment: That is weird. Shutting up, then. Will follow up if I find something useful.

Comment: Grazie Andrea. Eventually I will wait for a distribution to be released with the latest kernel. Hopefully they will not take too long...